# PhD-level textbooks on linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, reference-request, linear-algebra, phd

My graduate Linear Programming class uses Bertsimas & Tsitsiklis's [Introduction to Linear Optimization](http://www.athenasc.com/linoptbook.html). Are there any alternative texts that I could use to supplement this textbook (mainly the content of Chapter 2 of Bertsimas & Tsitsiklis: extreme point, vertex, basic feasible solution, contains/does not a line, Fourier-Motzkin) at the same level rigor and which contain exercises that I could practice on?

Ideally, I would also like a book with a decent (the more the better) number of pictures that gives geometric intuition behind proofs.

Comment: You can also checkout a relevant INFORMS open forum question here:  https://connect.informs.org/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=fc88c066-c1d1-4a4d-90cf-a90762c188d9&CommunityKey=1d5653fa-85c8-46b3-8176-869b140e5e3c&tab=digestviewer

Answer (score 12):

A classic textbook that does a really good job of building from the fundamentals is [*Theory of Linear and Integer Programming* by Schrijver](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Theory+of+Linear+and+Integer+Programming-p-9780471982326). Chapter 7 in particular gives great intuition on linear programming.

These [lecture notes by Ryan O'Donnell and Anupam Gupta](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/) are also a good, quicker reference as well as the textbook they refer to, [*Understanding and Using Linear Programming* by Matoušek and Gärtner](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540306979).

Comment: thanks @ydubey7. i think perhaps schrijver is a bit more high level than bertsimas. I really like gartner although i don't believe there's any exercises. are there any books similar to bertsimas chapter 2 with exercises I can practice on.

Answer (score 9):

I  used to study with the following book:

Chvatal, V. (1983). Linear programming.

Overall it's very clear. It's written primary for graduate courses in operations research, math and computer science. Chapter 17: Connections with Geometry, may give some geometric intuitions.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 8):

G.B. Dantzig and M.N. Thapa [Linear Programming 1: Introduction](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387948331), Springer, 1997 and
[Linear Programming 2: Theory and Extensions](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387986135), Spinger, 2003.

**Linear Programming 2, Theory and Extensions**, is the one with the hard-core theoretical Linear Programming Ph.D. material which you seem to want. Among other things, it contains some of the old Stanford O.R. Ph.D. comprehensive exam questions in Linear Programming - you won't find that in any other book.

Answer (score 7):

There are some good problems in *Linear Optimization: Theory and Extensions* by Fang and Puthenputra. Chapter 2 of the book ("Geometry of Linear Programming") is most comparable to Chapter 2 of Bertsimas.

Also see this related question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20643/669798

Comment: thanks, ill check it out.